# Embedding of $K_{2,3}$ into $\ell_1$

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces

I am looking for hints for the following problem:

Prove that every embedding of $K_{2,3}$ (with the shortest path metric and unit edge-length) into $\ell_1$ has distortion at least 4/3!

**Notation**: $\ell_1  = \cup_k(\mathbb{R}^k, ||.||^k_1)$, in which $(\mathbb{R}^k, ||.||^k_1)$ is the metric space with norm $||x||^k_1 = \sum_{i=1}^k|x_i|$ for any $x = (x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k$

A metric embedding is a function $f: (X,d_X) \rightarrow (Y,d_Y)$ that maps points of metric $(X,d_X)$ to points of $(Y,d_Y)$ such that $d_Y(f(x),f(y)) \geq d_X(x,y)$ and the distortion is $\sup_{x\not=y}\frac{d_Y(f(x),f(y))}{d_X(x,y)}$.

A graph $G$ (with non-negative edge weight) is said to be embeddable into $\ell_1$ with distortion $D$ if there exists an integer $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is an embedding of the shortest path metric of $G$ to $(\mathbb{R}^k, ||.||^k_1)$ with distortion at most $D$.